# Where can I download RTP pcap file with opus payload type?

Tags: audio, rtp, pcap, opus

I want to download RTP pcap with opus payload type. I find an example file at [here](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=sip-rtp-opus.pcap). Sampling rate and number of channels in this opus encoded packet respectively are 48000 KHz and 2. I want to check extra opus packets with another valid values for this parameters. Where can I find these files or How can I generate them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ffmpeg to generate the opus pcap :

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -channel_layout stereo -i audio="Microphone Array (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -c:a libopus -ab 48k -f rtp rtp://IP-Address:PORT
```

Change the Name Audio input device based on your PC's Audio device.